# Super Suckerfish drop downs hidden by aviaslider in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm having problems with this website [http://cspa.wa.edua.au](http://cspa.wa.edu.au).

The website is fine in most browsers however in IE the drop downs go behind the slider. I'm using aviaslider and super suckerfish for the navs.

Any CSS experts out there can have a quick look and let me know what I need to change so this problem is fixed.

Comment: Which version of IE? Malfunctions in IE7. Probably IE7's lack of compatibility with HTML5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with IE7 and is not to do with HTML5.  Instead it is a conflict with the z-index of the *aviaslider* and associated script.

Adding **position: relative** and **z-index: 99** to the `<nav>` element should fix the problem.

Comment: I commented above saying more or less exactly that, but my comment has disappeared. I think it was on a comment which was deleted. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment, although from my tests I deduced the z-index was required on the parent <nav> rather than the <ul>, which was worth pointing out.

Comment: Hey guys thanks just uploaded the updated code. Can you confirm if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the HTML5 shiv by the looks of it.

Try this in ur `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: He does the necessary element creation for IE in a local script.

Comment: Yes i use http://cspa.wa.edu.au/scripts/html5.js is their a difference between the two?